# how to use PaginationMode with PageLength and GapBetweenPages in cordova

Tags: html, cordova

In config.xml of cordova 3.5, there are things like PaginationMode, PageLength, GapBetweenPages, I wonder how to simply use it.

I've tried different values, but it seems none of them work on my webview.

Any examples of how to use it?